# maven модуль при сборке пытается подтянуть сам себя

Tags: java, maven

При *install* проекта выдает следующее:

> Failed to execute goal on project Ret: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.software.org:Ret:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.software.org:Ret:jar:1.0

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: неплохо было бы увидеть effective pom

Comment: на самого себя, но не совсем: у вас же версия `1.0-SNAPSHOT` а не может найти версию "1.0" видимо где-то еще она указывается